# Reading uninitialized unsigned int arrays from a packet in C

Tags: c, arrays, unsigned, packets

Im stuck with a problem of reading bytes in my C tcp socket server which receives request from a python client. I have the following struct as my receive template

```
struct ofp_connect {
uint16_t wildcards;                /* identifies ports to use below */
uint16_t num_components;           

uint8_t  pad[4];                   /* Align to 64 bits */

uint16_t in_port[0];               
uint16_t out_port[0];           

struct ofp_tdm_port in_tport[0];   
struct ofp_tdm_port out_tport[0];

struct ofp_wave_port in_wport[0];  
struct ofp_wave_port out_wport[0];

};
OFP_ASSERT(sizeof(struct ofp_connect) == 8);
```

I can read the first two 32 bit fields properly but my problem is the in_port[0] after the pad field that seems to be wrong. The way its currently being read is

```
uint16_t portwin, portwout, * wportIN;
wportIN =  (uint16_t*)&cflow_mod->connect.in_port; //where cflow_mod is the main struct which encompasses connect struct template described above 
memcpy(&portwin, wportIN, sizeof(portwin) );
DBG("inport:%d:\n", ntohs(portwin));
```

unfortunately this doesnt give me the expected inport number. I can check in wireshark that the client is sending the right packet format but I feel the way I read the in/out port is wrong. Or is it because of the way python sends the data? Can you provide some advice on where and why im going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the `struct ofp_connect` come from? The values of `in_port` and `out_port` are zero bytes in length (*i.e.*, no space is being allocated for them).

Comment: I'm surprised this even *compiles* with what is essentially two flexible arrays. It certainly does *not* on my toolchain (Apple LLVM 4.2 C99).

Comment: My mistake I didnt paste the entire structure since I was concentrating on the in/out_port fields.  Now its updated.

Comment: Your edit made things even worth. Now you have 6 flexible arrays ...S-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of struct ofp_connect violates the following clause of the ISO C standard:

> 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers ... 18 As a special case, the *last element* of a structure with more than one named member may   have
>   an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member.

Note that in your case `in_port` and `out_port` should have been declared as `in_port[]` and `out_port[]` to take advantage of the clause above in which case you would have *two* flexible array membes, which is prohibited by the above clause. The zero-length array declaration is a convention adopted by many compilers (including gcc, for example) which has the same semantics but in your case, both `in_port` and `out_port` *share the same space* (essentially whatever bytes follow the `ofp_connect` structure). Moreover, for this to work, you have to allocate some space after the structure for the flexible array members. Since, as you said, `struct connect` is part of a larger structure, accessing `in_port` returns the 'value' stored in the containing structure's member following the `connect` sub-`struct`

Comment: I have updated the structure now. This clears so many things the flexible arrays share the same space so I need to allocate memory.    uint16_t * wportIN [] = (uint16_t) malloc (2); //where 2 = sizeof(uint16_t) will this work?

Comment: by the by the statement uint16_t * wportIN =  (uint16_t*)&cflow_mod->connect.in_port; does allocate memory for it.

Comment: No, this is not going to work unfortunately. The idea is to allocate consecutive (with the structure) bytes. So, in your case, you need to do something like `connect_var = malloc( sizeof(struct ofp_connect) + 2*sizeof(uint16_t) )`. You can also declare both `port_in` and `port_out` as arrays of size 2 inside `ofp_connect` (i.e., say, `uint16_t port_in[2];`). The statement in your second comment makes the compiler reserve memory *for the pointer* but does not *allocate* (on the heap) any memory for the structure itself.

Comment: One final remark: making a structure with a flexible aray member part of another structure leads to undefined behavior according to the standard, so in your case you *have to* declare the size of port_in and port_out in advance, or rethink your approach altogether (maybe use a pointer to an ofp_connect instead of including it whole). You can still have only *one* flexible array, the other one has to have predetermined size (i.e. known at compilation time).

Comment: The problem I have is that the structures are part of a specification and its not recommended to change. Moreover since the number of ports are not know in advance it makes sense to have a flexible array. For these reasons I need to use these flexible arrays.